# ebtables.c:61:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'xt_compat_calc_jump' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Tags: android-kernel, lineageos

I am getting the following exception while building the recovery for a lineageos project and need some help diagnosing and resolving the issue

Device tree:= https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/android_device_lenovo_tb8504f/tree/lineage-15.1

Vendor tree:= https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/android_vendor_lenovo_tb8504f/tree/lineage-15.1

Kernel source:= https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/android_kernel_lenovo_tb8504f/tree/lineage-15.1

ROM Source:= https://github.com/LineageOS/android

Command: source build/envsetup.sh && breakfast tb8504f && repo sync --force-sync -q -j6 && mka recoveryimage -j6 | tee recovery.log

```
../../../../../../kernel/lenovo/msm8917/net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.c: In function 'ebt_standard_compat_from_user':
../../../../../../kernel/lenovo/msm8917/net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.c:61:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'xt_compat_calc_jump' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   v += xt_compat_calc_jump(NFPROTO_BRIDGE, v);
   ^
../../../../../../kernel/lenovo/msm8917/net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.c: At top level:
../../../../../../kernel/lenovo/msm8917/net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.c:76:15: error: variable 'ebt_standard_target' has initializer but incomplete type
 static struct xt_target ebt_standard_target = {
               ^
../../../../../../kernel/lenovo/msm8917/net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.c:77:2: error: unknown field 'name' specified in initializer
  .name       = "standard",
  ^
../../../../../../kernel/lenovo/msm8917/net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.c:77:2: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
error, forbidden warning: ebtables.c:77
  CC      net/core/gen_estimator.o
/home/lineageos/kernel/lenovo/msm8917/scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target 'net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.o' failed
make[4]: *** [net/bridge/netfilter/ebtables.o] Error 1
/home/lineageos/kernel/lenovo/msm8917/scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target 'net/bridge/netfilter' failed
make[3]: *** [net/bridge/netfilter] Error 2
/home/lineageos/kernel/lenovo/msm8917/scripts/Makefile.build:402: recipe for target 'net/bridge' failed
make[2]: *** [net/bridge] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Full log:

https://pastebin.com/v2ZsfRuc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by replacing the source in the include directory of this project with the include directory of another project.

I replaced the source with the source from this directory:

https://github.com/HighwayStar/android_kernel_lenovo_tb8704/tree/tab4-8plus-LA.UM.5.6.r1-0/include